# how to print tchar in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to print `UCHAR btMACAddress[INTEL_MAC_ADDR_LENGTH]` in c++.

```
cout<<"adapter MAC address="<<padapter->btMACAddress<<endl;
```

IT SHOWING NULL IS ABOVE

In c i am able to print.

```
printf("adapter macaddress  %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x \n",
       pAdapter->adapter[0].btMACAddress[0],
       pAdapter->adapter[0].btMACAddress[1],
       pAdapter->adapter[0].btMACAddress[2],
       pAdapter->adapter[0].btMACAddress[3],
       pAdapter->adapter[0].btMACAddress[4],
       pAdapter->adapter[0].btMACAddress[5]);
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example which shows your effort to fill and print `btMACAddress`?

Comment: ACTUALLY I AM SENDING ADDRESS OF STRUCTURE VARIABLE TO API. WHERE IT WILL FILL AND GIVE BACK US WIRELESS ADAPTER FEATURES. I AM WANT DISPLAY THE MAC ADDRESS.                                 cout<<"adapter MAC address="<<padapter->btMACAddress<<endl;

Comment: Did you accidentally hit caps lock before the comment?

Comment: yes accidentally i have pressed

Comment: You should do basically what you do in C (i.e. printing the bytes one after another), but using streams and [stream manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) for formatting.

Comment: You can use printf from C++ too.

Comment: I tried to fix your question up a bit, but I don't know what "IT SHOWING NULL IS ABOVE" means, so I left that alone.

Comment: yes i can print that.. but i want to print in c++.. using cout.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley the output is empty when i tried to execute using cout but with printf i am able to see output. thanks benjamin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joachim pointed out, you can use [stream manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) to control formatting of printed values.

Required headers file:

```
#include <ios>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
```

Code to print the MAC address:

```
cout << "adapter macaddress ";
for (int i=0; i<INTEL_MAC_ADDR_LENGTH; i++)
{
    if (i > 0) cout << ':';
    cout << hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') 
         << (unsigned int) pAdapter->adapter[0].btMACAddress[i];
}
cout << endl;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. what i have to do print a string with null terminated in c++.

Comment: @david It's the same operator: cout << mystring;

Comment: let me tell what i am trying to print. apart from mac address. if i try to print szAdapterDescription variable, printf("adapter description =%s \n",padapter->szAdapterDescription); output is : {22199-323-92323} iam getting correct out put but if i try to print using cout<<padapter->szAdapterDescription<<endl; i am not seeing any output. its not big problem but i am just wondering. thanks in advance

Comment: It would be better to post a new question. Your code seems correct to me, I don't know why it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{
     cout << pAdapter->adapter[0].btMACAddress[i];
}
cout << endl;
```

Also this has nothing to do with printing bytes but with your inability to use cout properly.

Comment: Thanks for finding my inability :). I am just wondering how cout will print any tchar defined variable. its not the way u tried to print byte by byte. that what i have done in c.